# translate a matrix in scheme

Tags: matrix, scheme, translate

Having trouble translating a matrix where the input would be two lists and the output would be the addition of the second list to every first such as:

```
(translate '((1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9)) '(10 20 30))
; -> ((11 22 33) (14 25 36) (17 28 39))
```

I currently have:

```
(define (translate matrix1 matrix2)
    (if (list? (car matrix1))
        (append '() (map + (car matrix1) matrix2)) 
        (translate (cdr matrix1) matrix2)))
```

I think this will keep appending each car of matrix1 everytime I recursively call to an empty list but I'm only getting my first 'row' to output.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

That would be as easy as

```
(define (translate matrix1 matrix2)
  (map (lambda (lst) (map + lst matrix2)) matrix1))
```

Testing

```
> (translate '((1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9)) '(10 20 30))
'((11 22 33) (14 25 36) (17 28 39))
```

Comment: @PedroRivas If this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Otherwise, don't hesitate to get back to us.